# Controlling adobe acrobat with apple script and mac.remote app

Tags: android, applescript, acrobat

I am trying to use the mac.remote app on my android phone to act as a presentation clicker for pdf presentations using adobe acrobat pro.

I have set up the commands as follows:

```
tell app "Adobe Acrobat" to fullscreen

tell app "Adobe Acrobat" to key code 123

tell app "Adobe Acrobat" to key code 124
```

However, I am getting no response whats so ever. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Applescript support of Acrobat is dismal, unfortunately. You will have to carefully look at the documentation, as well as what the dictionary tells you.

In many cases, the best you can do is either run a JavaScript, and when that comes short, use System Events to work with the user interface. A little bit messy, but you get quite far with this approach.